# How can make react re-render instantly after clicking like/unlike button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I added like and unlike buttons to my react app. I'm using redux to manage the state and storing the data in firebase realtime-database. The buttons are working as they should but I need to reload the page to show the post has been liked/unliked, it is not re-rendering on its own. I tried using both forceUpdate and setState but both didn't work.

```
postLiked = (id) => {
   this.props.onLikePost(this.props.user, id)
   this.forceUpdate()
}

postUnliked = (id, unlikeID) => {
   this.props.onUnlikePost(id, unlikeID)
}

render() {
           {this.props.data.map((res) => {     
       
               const liked = [];
               for(let key in res.LikedBy){
                       liked.push({
                       ...res.LikedBy[key],
                       id: key
                   });
               }

               let boolButton = false;
               if(liked.filter((val) => {
                   if(val.username === this.props.user) {
                       boolButton = true
                   }
               }))
       return(
       <div>
                 
                   <div className="bottomButtons">
                 
                   {boolButton ? <Button className="btn btn-primary likeDislike"
                   id="likeButton"
                   onClick={() => this.postUnliked(res.id, liked.find((val) => {
                       if(val.username === this.props.user){
                           return val.id;
                       }
                   }))}
                    >
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faThumbsUp} style={{width:"13.5px", color:"white"}}/>
                    </Button> : <Button className="btn btn-light likeDislike"
                   id="likeButton"
                   onClick={() => this.postLiked(res.id)}
                   >
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faThumbsUp} style={{width:"13.5px"}}/>
                    </Button>
                     }
```

These are the action functions

```
export const likePost = (username, postId) => {
const req = {
    username,
    postId
}
return (dispatch) => {
    axios.post('/Data/' + postId + '/LikedBy.json', req)
    .then((res) => {
       dispatch({
           type: actionTypes.Like_Post,
           payload: res
       })
    })
}
}

export const unlikePost = (id, unlikeId) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.delete('/Data/' + id + '/LikedBy/' + unlikeId.id + '.json')
        .then((res) => {
           dispatch({
               type: actionTypes.Unlike_Post
           })
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
    }
```

And this is the reducer function

```
const initialState = {
    Data: []
  }

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => { 
    switch(action.type){
     
      case actionTypes.Like_Post: 
      return {
        ...state,
        Data: state.Data.map((post) => post.id === action.payload.postId
        ? {...post, LikedBy: post.LikedBy.concat(action.payload.username)}:post),
        loading: false,
      }

      case actionTypes.Unlike_Post: 
      return {
        ...state,
        Data: state.Data,
        loading: false,
      }
```

**EDIT**
I tried other methods but nothing is working. The issue is with the reducer and I am not correctly updating the state. I tried updating the LikedBy field but I only get an error.
Tried this approach but I got an error saying res.map is not a function

```
 case actionTypes.Like_Post:
      return {
        ...state,
        Data: state.Data.forEach((res) => res.map((q) => {
          if(q.id === action.payload.postId) {
            q.LikedBy.concat(action.payload.username)
           }
           return q
          })
        )
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be re-loading the page to upload this state really (don't listen to people who tell you to do it); this is one of the many problems that React was designed to solve. The reason you are having an issue is because your component isn't SEEING a change to its data therefor a re-render is not being triggered, this is most likely because you aren't passing the correct prop into your component.

Your redux reducer is referring to `Data` but locally in your component you are using `this.props.data` try making sure you are actually passing your data reducer properly into the component.